# Prove that $\text{rot(grad}f)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms

Prove that $\text{rot(grad}f)=0$

$X$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R^n}$, $\omega$ it's a form

$X\mapsto \omega \mapsto d\omega \mapsto *(d\omega)=\text{rot}X$

(This is a problem from do Carmo's differential forms.)

---

$\text{grad}f=\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i} \mapsto \sum _{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i$

now if I apply the exterior derivative

$\bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^1\partial x^1}dx^1+...+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^n\partial x^1}dx^n \bigg)\wedge dx^1+...+ \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^1\partial x^n}dx^1+...+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^n\partial x^n}dx^n \bigg)\wedge dx^n=$

$=  \Bigg[\bigg(- \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^1\partial x^2}\bigg)dx^1\wedge dx^2 + \bigg(- \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^3\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^1\partial x^3}\bigg)dx^1\wedge dx^3+...+ \bigg(- \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^n\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^1\partial x^3}\bigg)dx^1\wedge dx^n\Bigg]+ +\Bigg[\bigg(- \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^3\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2\partial x^3}\bigg)dx^2\wedge dx^3+...+\bigg(- \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^n\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2\partial x^n}\bigg)dx^2\wedge dx^n\Bigg]+...+\Bigg[  \bigg( - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^n\partial x^{n-1}}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^{n-1}\partial x^n}  \bigg)dx^{n-1}\wedge dx^n\Bigg]\mapsto 0=\text{rot(grad}f)$

Is my solution correct ?

Comment: Has doCarmo not yet proved that $d(d\eta)=0$ for any form $\eta$? How does that apply directly here?

Comment: Aren't you just trying to prove $\nabla\times\nabla f=0$, which holds since partial derivatives commute?

Comment: @g.s I think the point of this problem is to use forms to show that.

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought of that too, but I couldn't show how that apply here, maybe $\omega=dX $ so $d\omega=d(dX)$ ? I am not sure. Although you didn't verify my answer, neither as correct nor incorrect, I would appreciate if you could do that, because I spend some important time thinking it and writing it on Latex.

Comment: Yes, in fact $\omega. = df$ and you actually redid the proof in this case.  You should comment that because $f$ is $C^2$ these coefficients vanish.